# Django - Can't read media files

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library

I'm using Django to create a website where you can upload an image on that website and check if the image contains Moire pattern. Here is the project structure:

[image: Project structure]

In file settings.py, I specified the following directory for media files:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

and in file views.py, I implemented the API that will receive the image and detect moire pattern like this:

```
from django.core.files.storage import default_storage
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        f = request.FILES['sentFile']
        response = {}
        fname = 'pic.jpg'
        fname2 = default_storage.save(fname, f)
        file_url = default_storage.url(fname2)
        image = Image.open(file_url)
        pred_label = moire_detect(image)
        response['label'] = pred_label
        return render(request, 'frontpage.html', response)
    else:
        return render(request, 'frontpage.html')
```

However, when I try to open the image using Image module of Pillow, I got this error "No such file or directory: '/media/pic_O1TOyCK.jpg'".

I don't really understand what is happening here, because the path is correct. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: `Image.open` doesn't use `url` but normal `path` - but `file_url` which has `/media/pic_O1TOyCK.jpg'` is useful to create URL in HTML (like `http://localhost/media/pic_O1TOyCK.jpg`) but not to access local file. You should rather use `fname2` with `Image.open`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Image.open` doesn't work with `url` but with normal `path`.

But `file_url` has `/media/pic_O1TOyCK.jpg` which is `relative url` and it can be used on HTML (to get `http://localhost/media/pic_O1TOyCK.jpg`) but it can't be used as normal path to access directly local file.

You should rather use `fname2` with `Image.open()`